# No entra en la funcion addEventListener de un FileReader en función Javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un container para mostrar una vista previa de las imágenes que se han subido y desde hace unos días no me funciona el evento addEventListener de una función en javascript. Debo decir que cuando lo desarrollé lo estuve testeando y funcionaba así que no se en qué momento ni porqué ha dejado de funcionar. No he hecho ningún cambio en la función. Os pido vuestra ayuda porque he probado a llamarla de otras formas (.onload) y no logro que se muestre la imagen.

```js
let num=0;
function readImage() {
 if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
  var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
  var output = $(".preview-images-zone"); //--> div contenedor de imagénes

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   var file = files[i];
   var idImg = (file["name"].split(".")[0]).replace(/ /g, "");
   if (!file.type.match('image')) continue;

   var picReader = new FileReader();

   picReader.addEventListener('load', function (event) { // --> aqui no entra
    var picFile = event.target;
    var html = '<div class="preview-image preview-show-' + num + '" id="' + idImg + '">' +
     '<div class="image-cancel" data-no="' + num + '">x</div>' +
     '<div class="image-zone" id="image-zone-' + num + '"><img id="pro-img-' + num + '" src="' + picFile.result + '"></div>' +
     '</div>';

    output.append(html);
    num = num + 1; //--> no hace la suma
   });

   picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
 } else {
  console.log('Browser not support');
 }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

    <fieldset class="form-group" id="fieldsetId">
            <a id="uploadLink" href="javascript:void(0)" data-no="0">Subir imagen</a>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Sólo jpg,jpeg,png y gif con tamaño máximo de 5 MB.</small>
            <input type="file" id="pro-image" name="pro-image[]" accept="image/*" onchange="readImage()" class="form-control" multiple>
        </fieldset>
        <div id="imgContainer" class="preview-images-zone"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Te has asegurado que no entra con un `console.log()` al principio de la función? ¿Has comprobado que la variable `file` este bien?

Comment: File contiene la imagen que he seleccionado y he puesto un console.log() dentro del addEventListener y variables y no hace nada.. Por más vueltas que le doy no consigo ver el fallo. ¿Puede ser un problema de configuración? he comentado que antes si me funcionaba y el código es el mismo

Comment: El código funciona, no veo el problema. Voto como no reproducible. Si no te funciona mira los errores de la consola y comprueba otras partes del código.

Comment: Efectivamente el código funciona. Lo acabo de probar en safari y desde mi móvil y no da problemas. Tiene que ser un problema de configuración de Chrome. Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo y ayuda!!

Comment: Lo unico, no se si hara que funcione en ese caso o no, pero hara el script más optimizado. Saca la declaración del FileReader y la asignación del evento fuera del bucle. No es necesario crear nuevos FileReaders

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo he sacado fuera del loop. He visto que cuando se muestra la imagen el src es una cadena interminable, puede ser ese el error o es correcto? document.getElementById('pro-img-0').src=
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAMAAADDpiTIAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAACXBIWXMAAEx+AABMfgGQ2kXEAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQB3d3cuaW5rc2NhcGUub3Jnm+48GgAAAwBQTFRF//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.........IIYQQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBC4uS/LSKdeAiU05IAAAAASUVORK5CYII="

Comment: Vale, funciona si cierro el depurador, con la barra de herramientas para desarrolladores abierta no me muestra las imágenes y si la cierro sí las muestra. No entiendo nada jejeje. Lo dejo así, doy por cerrado el tema. Muchisimas gracias de nuevo por vuestros comentarios